# Can you change a failed Github PR description/context from Travis-CI?

Tags: travis-ci

The [github api](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/) allows you to add a 'context' to the failed pull request as well as a description. Travis-CI adds a description of 'Failed — The Travis CI build failed'. It would be nice if you could add a context to that too, so that you could say the 'integration' tests had failed or just give some more information.

So is it possible to change your .travis.yml file so that you can specify more information in the github failure message? Perhaps set an environment variable with a string that becomes the failure context?

Comment: This may be a feature request; those can be filed at https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues